# chat room whit gif and emoji and image Java

Tags: java, image, swing, gif, emoji

I want to build a chat room whit java swing.

I want to have a component to show text, image, gif and emoji.

please help me to select a good component.

In first I choose JtextPane for this.Is it good?

Comment: Hi Ali, unfortunately your question is too broad and should be closed as off topic. Please read [ask] before posting to Stack Overflow

Comment: Hint: turn the content into HTML and then look for a component the renders HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In first I choose JtextPane for this.Is it good?

Yes, I would use a JTextPane, with normal text (not HTML). With a JTextPane you can:

1. text with attributes.
2. align text to the right/left of the text pane
3. display icons using the insertIcon(...) method.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Text Component Features](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html) for some examples that use attributes when adding text.